# Xamarin Add Nuget package (anyone) and my app says unfortunately app has stopped

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have a Xamarin app in Android and it's running well, but when I add some Nuget package and try deploy in smartphones with API 20 or lower it says: unfortunately app has stopped, and don't run the application.

I already tried uncheck multi-dex, ProGuard, Shared Runtime and don't work, but if I revert to before add Nuget it works fine.

I already have the same problem when I trying add some axml files but after clean somethings in project, the problem dissapear.

Can you help me, please?

Comment: `some Nuget package`? What package are you adding?

Comment: I tried with AndroidViewAnimations and Xamarin.RecyclerView.SwipeMenu after install I can't run the application

Comment: In your Solution Exploer, choose Properties -> Android Options -> Linking -> SDK Assemblies Only, and try again.

Comment: @YorkShen doesn't work.. I can not add any package to the principal project, but if I add NuGet packages to others projects in solution don't give me any error and run nicelly.